# Paypal ASP.NET without credit card management

Tags: asp.net, paypal, sdk

I'm starting to use Paypal SDK to implement the payment service for a ASP.NET site. I wrote the code following the SDK example and everything worked fine, of course I'm managing the whole process (credit card data entry and submission included). The site owner however complained about credit card data management and thus asked me to re-implement the whole procedure without managing the credit card data 'internally' **at all** but leaving Paypal doing this part of the job.
This mean that NO data of the credit card should be entered in forms belonging to the site I'm coding.
As far as I can see (but I'm just a newbie in Paypal SDK) there's not a way to do what I'm asked for using SDK API calls.

Given my lack of experience I'm not sure about what I'm stating then I can only suppose that I'm missing something so... there's a way to do so trough API calls?

Best Regards,
 Mike

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not PayPal customer support. Check their documentation or contact their customer support for info on how to use their libraries. If you have a specific programming problem, that would be more appropriate for SO.

Comment: Hallo mason please consider that Paypal community support forum points to StackOverflow page. Obvioulsy reading the whole Paypal developer documentation (and taking about 1/2 years of time) I would have a clear answer to what's my need. Anyway I will continue reading docs helping myself. IMHO this's not elegible as a community forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your site owner is likely asking you to do is to leverage **PayPal's [Vault API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview/)** (part of its REST APIs) to store credit card information so your site doesn't have to.  If you store the credit card information on your site, you have to ensure the data is stored in a PCI-compliant manner, which may be too costly for some sites.  The Vault API will return a credit card token that can only be used by your REST application for making payments.  The API also allows you to get the details of the credit card using the token, but will mask the full credit card number.

There are some examples on how to do this in the [PayPal .NET SDK Samples](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/master/Samples/Source/CreateCreditCard.aspx.cs#L43). If there's a use case that's missing, feel free to let us know over on [GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/issues).

Comment: Nope... this's not what the site owner is asking its request it is not to deal with credit card data at all ... I mean the site should redirect to paypal prior the credit card data input and get pack just after the transaction is completed. I'm actually using the Paypal REST API and it works fine but as long as I see there's no way to trigger a redirection to paypal site to manage all the credit card data I/O without having to collect them and pass them to paypal trough API calls (that's what I'm already doing and that triggered the complains about the site owner).

Comment: @weirdgyn Based on the question asked, that's what I assumed: "The site owner however complained about credit card data management and thus asked me to re-implement the whole procedure without managing the credit card data 'internally' but leaving Paypal doing this part of the job."  This is ambiguous and you may want to edit your question to properly reflect what it is you're seeking.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you're looking to only accept PayPal payments (e.g. `payment.payer.payment_method = "paypal"`) and not direct credit card payments.

Comment: @weirdgyn To further clarify, a [PayPal payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/) will allow a buyer to choose to pay with their PayPal balance or an account linked to their PayPal account (i.e. a linked bank account or credit card).  Then, your site will not need to worry about storing any credit card data.

Comment: I just edited my first question to point out what the site owner means. In the solution I coded I was using the Paypal Payment this lead me to collect credit card data trough a form housed in my site and this's just what the site owner complains about. Then Paypal Payment it's not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: It might also help if you share the code you've written that's making the SDK call - specifically, how you're defining the `Payment` object prior to calling `Payment.Create()`.  To do what you're looking for, you should just need to set `payment.payer.payment_method = "paypal"`.  This allows the buyer to pay with their PayPal account, meaning they can use their PayPal balance or a credit card or bank account they have attached to their PayPal account.  This removes the need for you to store any credit card data in your system.

Comment: Hallo @Jason Z as you suggested the solution was to use the `payment.payer.payment_method = "paypal"` . In the first release of my code I was folled to use `credit_card` and that lead to this mess. Anyway I also noticed that, using such methods of payment, Paypal sometimes allows to pay without account creation and sometime does not... (probably it depends on the location the remote user comes from).

Answer (score 1):

PayPal basics for ASP.net c#

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/718003/How-implement-Strong-cryptography-with-associated
http://forums.asp.net/t/1977404.aspx?Integrate+with+Paypal+account+within+Net+project
http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/PayPalIntegration/PayPalIntegration.asp
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
What you suggest is correct but there's still not a clear answer to my question. Besides best practices to manage credit card data as a general security policy my customer wont allow to manage them. The real question is then if there's a way among the Paypal world to allow payment trough credit card (without requiring Paypal account) leaving Paypal to manage just the credit card data management (autorization etc). Reading and exploring examples and docs from Paypal itself I'm figuring out that this's not possibile.